# ORMLite on Android: Getting NullPointerException when trying to read data from object

Tags: android, ormlite

In my application I have several persisted models and in one case I'm getting exception when trying to get data using corresponding getter. But there is data in tha DB and I have no idea why getter returns nothing.
Answer class:

```
@DatabaseTable
@JsonRootName(value = "answer")
public class Answer {
    public Answer() {}        

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName = "_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Integer id;

    @DatabaseField
    @JsonProperty(value = "id")
    private Integer answer_id;

    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.LONG_STRING)
    private String text;
    // some other fields and setters/getters
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

Question class:

```
@DatabaseTable
public class Question extends BaseDaoEnabled implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7587892134579897L;

    public Question() {
    }
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
    private Answer answer;
}
```

Quest class:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "quests")
@JsonRootName(value = "quest")
public class Quest {

@DatabaseField(allowGeneratedIdInsert = true, generatedId = true, columnName = "_id")
private Integer id;

@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.DATE_STRING)
Date created_at;

@DatabaseField(foreign = true)
private Survey survey;

@ForeignCollectionField(eager = false, orderColumnName = "question_id")
public Collection<Question> questions;
```

Answer creation:

```
  answer.setText(input.getText().toString());
  try {
      if (answer.getId() == null) {
          DBHelperFactory.GetHelper().getAnswersDao().create(answer);
          question.setAnswer(answer);
          DBHelperFactory.GetHelper().getQuestionsDao().update(question);
      } else  {
          DBHelperFactory.GetHelper().getAnswersDao().update(answer);
      }
      Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "Answer saved", 5).show();
      listener.nextQuestion();
  } catch (SQLException e) {
      Log.e(LOG_KEY, "Create failed", e);
  }
```

And the failing code, (quest is passed in to the function that is running in the background)

```
for (Question question : quest.questions) {
    if (question.getAnswer() != null) {
         Log.d(LOG_KEY, question.getId().toString());
         Log.d(LOG_KEY, question.getAnswer().getId().toString());
         Log.d(LOG_KEY, question.getAnswer().getText());
         // NullPointerException for getText().
    }
}
```

`getAnswer()` indeed returns Answer. Data in DB persisted. But `getText()` is failing.
Can anyone please help me to find out where I am wrong?

Comment: where are you setting the text of the answer?

Comment: oh i see, you sure that answer.setText(input.getText().toString()); gets executes correctly?

Comment: Yes, because when i dump the db from device (emulator) end look what it exactly contains i can see the data added.

Comment: How are you querying for `quest`.  Can you show that code?  Also you _don't_ need to do the `update(...)` after the creates.

Comment: Added Quest code. Quest instance is passed to function. Why update is not needed after setting reference to Answer? May there be some issues wit datatypes?

Comment: Eventually when I changed dataType from LONG_STRING to String - problem has solved. Gray, can it be somehow related to broken LONG_STRING support under Android (closed issue #36 on SF)? I'm using ORMlite version 4.42. Shall I create a corresponding issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key was that `@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.LONG_STRING)` works strange and I couldn't managed to make it work. After switching back to `VARCHAR` - problem dissappeared.